# parenting rebel inherit html

Tags: html, inheritance

i made a "div" element as the father element, and inside added the "p" and "img", **but somehow they're not inside the perent limits, the "p" its overlaping the other "p" and they respond to the full html width ween resize the page**, its better to see the code:

```
<div>
    <h1>***</h1> <!--"h1" is responding well-->
    <p>
    ***
    </p>
    <p>
    ***
    </p>
    <img src="***.jpg" title="***">
</div>
```

the css is

```
div {
margin: 20 10 0 10;
padding: 10 10 20 10;
}

div>h1 {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 20 auto;
}

div>p {
position: absolute;
display: block;
left: 0;
width:45%;
margin: 0 5 10 5; 
}

div>img {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 45%;
margin: 0 5 10 5;
}
```

> i also aplied the reset file of html formating since the beginning,
>
> > html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
> >     v1.6.1
> >     Last Updated: 2010-09-17
> >     Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
> >     Twitter: @rich_clark

i can only add that it hapened after changing page, i think it was not the reason but it was inside the "div" in the beginning and somehow it turned in rebel elements!!

i restarted the chrome and the brackets, but the error keeps going on.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary issues here:

1) You have two `<p>` elements that occupy the same space because they are each styled with the same definition for `position: absolute`.

2) The children `<div class="p">` and `<img src>` elements from your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kzrod55/) appear outside of their parent `<div>` because they are each floated. Although adding `display: inline-block` worked in your updated fiddle, this is not a good idea since it can introduce inconsistencies elsewhere in your code. Floated elements fall outside of the natural flow of a page and do not inherit the characteristics of the parent. To get around this, you must "clear the float."

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kajcu38o/).

More Information:
`http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/`
`http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp`

Comment: Please make a fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please comment if you have further questions.

Comment: ok the parent dont work but the .cf its perfect, i changed my code and you can add this http://jsfiddle.net/freakhealer/kajcu38o/1/ to your final answer. (i take out the parent child and keep the important) thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the display of the div, it was like:

> http://jsfiddle.net/8kzrod55/

and i naifly  added:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/8kzrod55/2/

its not fully styled because its a beggining but its ok in my page.

actually if some one knows what hapened, why the "div" naturaly a 'block' element dont keep the content inside, i would apreciate the expanation.

thanks guys ! especialy to *Praveen Kumar* that answered this on other question with another topic!! ahah

Comment: i studied the links you gave me, and .cf {
    *zoom: 1 /*for ie 6/7 */;
    overflow: auto;
} solve it ..